# Find elements in an integer array such that their sum is X and sum of their square is least

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Given an array `arr` of length `n`, find any elements within `arr` such that their sum is `x` and sum of their squares is least. I'm trying to find the algorithm with least complexity. So far, I've written a simple recursive algorithm that finds all the subset within array and put the sum check as base condition. I've written my code is javascript as below:

```
var arr = [3, 4, 2, 1];
var arr2 = arr.map(function(n) { return n*n; });

var max_sum = 5;
var most_min = -1;

function _rec(i, _sum, _square) {
    if(_sum >= max_sum) {
        if(most_min == -1 || _square < most_min) {
            most_min = _square;
            console.log("MIN: " + most_min);
        }
        console.log("END");
        return;
    }

    if(i >= arr.length)
        return;

    console.log(i);
    var n = arr[i];
    // square of above number
    var n2 = arr2[i];    
    _sum = _sum + n;
    _square = _square + n2;
    _rec(i+1, _sum, _square);

    _sum = _sum - n;
    _square = _square - n2;
    _rec(i+1, _sum, _square);
}

_rec(0, 0, 0);
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/1dxgq6d5/6/ to see the output of above algorithm. Above algorithm is quite simple, it is finding all subsets by evaluating two choices at every recursive step; 1) choose the current number or 2) reject and then carry on with recursion.

I'm trying to find an algorithm which is more efficient then simple recursion above. Any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

### One more hypothesis

I'm thinking that if I sort the array, and find the subset of element with least variance (separations between each other) such that their sum is `x` would fulfill my requirements. Not sure, if this is going to be very helpful, but I'm currently working this in hope to improve my current blind recursive approach.

Comment: Least variance is useful, and so is having lots of small numbers instead of a single bigger number: for example, using 4 and 6 is better than using 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in more efficient way than simple recursion. I'm using dynamic programming approach. Below is the python code I wrote:

```
_sum=7
_set=[1,1,2,3,4,6]

current_idx = 0

sum_mapping = [[-1 for i in range(len(_set) + 1)] for i in range(_sum)]
max_sum = _set[current_idx]
for i in range(0, _sum):
    current_sum = i + 1
    for j in [i for i in range(0, current_idx+1)][::-1] + \
        [i for i in range(current_idx + 1, len(_set))]:
        required_value = current_sum - _set[j]
        if required_value < 0:
            break
        if required_value == 0 or sum_mapping[required_value - 1][j] != -1:
            _j = j + 1
            sum_mapping[i][_j:] = [j]*(len(_set) - j)
            break
    if max_sum == current_sum:
        current_idx = current_idx + 1
        max_sum = max_sum + _set[current_idx]

_cur = sum_mapping[_sum-1][len(_set)]

if _cur != -1:
    _l_sum = _sum
    while _l_sum != 0:
        print(_set[_cur])
        _l_sum = _l_sum - _set[_cur]
        _cur = sum_mapping[_l_sum -1][len(_set)]
```

Here is ideone output: http://ideone.com/OgGN2f

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're finding subsets, not permutations, because you don't care about the order of the elements in each set.

Secondly, even without trying to minimize the sum of the squares, just finding whether there's a subset that sums to a target number is NP-complete -- this is the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  It's currently believed by most computer scientists that P != NP, so there's no efficient (polynomial-time) algorithm for this.

Answer (score 1):

Subset sum is only weakly NP-hard, so it's possible to get an efficient solution with dynamic programming (assuming that the input array consists of integers having a relatively small sum). Switch from trying all possibilities recursively and depth-first to trying all possibilities iteratively and breadth-first by storing the possibilities for the first k elements in an array. Before considering element k + 1, filter this array by discarding all but the lowest sum of squares for each total that can be made.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used dynamic programming approach for the efficient algorithm